# Writer not writing text to file in subdirectory on close

Tags: java, file

I have a very simple operation of writing some text to a file in a subdirectory. By all tutorials I have seen, this should work, but the file remains empty every time. It works when not writing to a subdirectory, no exceptions are thrown.

```
File file = new File("./Decks");

public void saveDeck(Deck deck) {
    File deckFile = new File(file, deck.getName() + ".xml");

    try {
        if(!deckFile.exists()){
            deckFile.createNewFile();
        }


        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(deckFile.getName()), "utf-8"));
        writer.write(deck.toXml());
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }

}
```

Here's what the deck class looks like:

```
public class Deck {
String name;
String cardLocation;

public Deck(String name, String cardLocation) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cardLocation = cardLocation;
}

public String toXml(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?> \n");
    builder.append("<deck> \n");
    builder.append("<name> " + this.name + " </name> \n");
    builder.append("<cardLocation> " + this.cardLocation + " </cardLocation> \n");
    builder.append("</deck> \n");
    return builder.toString();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCardLocation() {
    return cardLocation;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? What do you have in `deck`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.getName()` returns the filename part of a path,
without the parent directories.

Given this:

> ```
> File file = new File("./Decks");
>
> // ...
>
> File deckFile = new File(file, deck.getName() + ".xml");
> ```

The result of `deckFile.getName()` is `deck.getName() + ".xml"`.
The path part is lost.

So the fix is to simply replace `deckFile.getName()` with `deckFile`:

```
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(deckFile), "utf-8"));
writer.write(deck.toXml());
writer.close();
```

Comment: Sorry, this was unclear in how I asked the question, deck.getName() just returns a string. If I follow the constructor for file correctly, File(file, fileName) is the equivalent of doing ./Decks/fileName

Comment: @EricH I guess my message could be more clear. The problem is with `new FileOutputStream(deckFile.getName())`. This will remove the path part from `deckFile`. It needs to be `new FileOutputStream(deckFile)`.